Latex annotations on plotly
Does anyone comes to know how can I add latex annotation into a plot displayed by plotly?
I have searched and it says that using something likes this xaxis_title=r'$\sqrt{(n_\text{c}(t|{T_\text{early}}))}$',  should enable you to have the latex format.
But i do not know how to implement that into my code
annotations = []
def add_annotations_and_lines(fig, final_E1,i):
    
    # Extract the necessary values from final_E1
    names = [element[2] for element in final_E1]
    energyvalues = [round(element[0], 3) for element in final_E1]
    y_peaks = [round(element[3], 3) for element in final_E1]


    # Create the y values for the vertical lines
    y_values = np.zeros(3 * len(y_peaks))
    y_values[1::3] = y_peaks
    y_values[2::3] = None

    energylevel = ['_1', '_2']
    colors= ['black','blue']
    # Adding annotations with the names and energy levels
    for energy, y_peak, element_name in zip(energyvalues, y_peaks, names):
        if i < len(energylevel):
            level = energylevel[i]
        else:
            level = ""
        annotations.append(dict(
            x=energy,
            y=y_peak,
            text=f'{element_name}_{level}<br>{energy}',
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=2,
            ax=0,  # Centered horizontally
            ay=-40,  # Vertical offset
            font=dict(
                size=12,
                color="black"
            ),
            bordercolor=colors[i],
            borderwidth=2,
            borderpad=4,
            bgcolor="white",
            opacity=0.8
        ))

    fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)

    return fig

The returned figure is this oneFigure
I tried using text=r'${element_name}_{level}{energy}$' but did not work.

You don't need to r if you're not using the slash character. Just keep it as an f string, and wrap it in the dollar signs to signify that it's latex.
